# Resolved database context yields null DbSet(s)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have 3 assemblies in my project: `MyApp.Core`, `MyApp.Infrastructure`, `MyApp.Web`.

`MyApp.Core` contains database models/entities, `MyApp.Infrastructure` contains the database context and migrations, and `MyApp.Web` contains the `Startup` class.

The database was created using code first EF and it exists (I checked).

I've registered the database context in my `Startup` class's `ConfigureServices` method:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add framework services.
        services.AddDbContext<MyAppDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        services.AddIdentity<Employee, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<KinderGardenDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
        ...
    }
```

I want to seed my database using my static method `MyApp.Infrastructure.MyAppContextSeed.Seed()`. So I add the method at the end of the `Configure` method:

```
...
   MyAppDbContextSeed.Seed(app.ApplicationServices).Wait();
}
```

In the above method, I resolve the database context:

```
public static async Task Seed(IServiceProvider services)
{
    ...
    using (var context = services.GetRequiredService<MyAppDbContext>())
    using (var roleManager = services.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>())
    using (var userManager = services.GetRequiredService<UserManager<Employee>>())
    {
        if (!await context.Companies.AnyAsync())
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

**In the `if` statement above, `Companies` is null.**

Also, here is my database context class:

```
namespace MyApp.Infrastructure.EntityFramework
{
    public class MyAppDbContext : IdentityDbContext<Employee>
    {
        public DbSet<Company> Companies;
        public DbSet<Person> Persons;
        public DbSet<Employee> Employees;
        public DbSet<KeyCard> KeyCards;
        public DbSet<KeyRequestForm> KeyRequestForms;

        public KinderGardenDbContext(DbContextOptions<KinderGardenDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);

            builder.Entity<Company>().ToTable("Company");
            builder.Entity<Person>().ToTable("Person");
            builder.Entity<Employee>().ToTable("Employee");
            builder.Entity<KeyCard>().ToTable("KeyCard");
            builder.Entity<KeyRequestForm>().ToTable("KeyRequestForm");

            builder.Entity<KeyCardKeyRequestForm>().ToTable("KeyCardKeyRequestForm");

            builder.Entity<KeyCardKeyRequestForm>()
                .HasKey(c => new { c.KeyCardId, c.KeyRequestFormId });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because your DbSet properties aren't actually properties :) ... they are fields. Make them properties with a getter and setter and